# how to sort data inside text file in accending order in python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, helper

I have a text file containing number integer and string value pairs I want to sort them in ascending order but I am not getting it correct

**TextFile.txt **

```
87,Toronto
45,USA
45,PAKISTAN
33,India
38,Jerry
30,Tom
23,Jim
7,Love
38,Hate
30,Stress
```

**My code**

```
def sort_outputFiles():
    print('********* Sorting now **************')
    my_file = open("TextFile.txt", "r",encoding='utf-8')
    data = my_file.read()
    data_into_list = data.split("\n")
    my_file.close()
    score=[]
    links=[]
    for d in data_into_list:
        if d != '':
            s=d.split(',')
            score.append(s[0])
            links.append(s[1])
    n = len(score)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(0, n-i-1):
            if score[j] < score[j+1]:
                score[j], score[j+1] = score[j+1], score[j]
                links[j], links[j+1] = links[j+1], links[j]

    for l,s in zip(links,score):
        print(l," ",s)
```

**My output**

```
********* Sorting now **************
Toronto   87
Love   7
USA   45
PAKISTAN   45
Jerry   38
Hate   38
India   33
Tom   30
Stress   30
Jim   23
```

**Expected output**

```
********* Sorting now **************
Toronto   87
USA   45
PAKISTAN   45
Jerry   38
Hate   38
India   33
Tom   30
Stress   30
Jim   23
Love   7
```

having error at line 2 in out put it should be in last

Comment: The scores are stored and compared as strings (lexicographically), convert them to int numbers before sorting.

Comment: Change `score.append(s[0])` to `score.append(int(s[0]))`

Comment: Any reason not using the list.sort method or the sorted function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings, not numbers.

In an dictionary (like, the physical book), the words are sorted by who has the "lowest" first letter, and if it's a tie, we pick the lowest second letter, and so on. This is called lexicographical order.

So the string "aaaa" < "ab". Also, "1111" < "12"

To fix this, you have to convert the string to a number (using `int(s[0])` instead of `s[0]` in the `score.append` function).

This will make 1111 > 12. Your code will give the correct result.

Comment: oooh i seee let me check

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function to sort the list. If you use the `key` parameter, you can specify a custom sorting behaviour, and if you use the `reverse` parameter, you can sort in descending order.

Also, you can use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to make reading your input file easier.

```py
import csv

with open("TextFile.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as csvfile:
    lines = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
for line in sorted(lines, key=lambda l: int(l[0]), reverse=True):
    print(f"{line[1]} {line[0]}")
```

Output:

```
Toronto 87
USA 45
PAKISTAN 45
Jerry 38
Hate 38
India 33
Tom 30
Stress 30
Jim 23
Love 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your intentions, but a compact implementation would be like:

```
with open('textfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = [l.split(',') for l in f.readlines()]
d=[(dd[1][:-1], int(dd[0])) for dd in d]
d_sorted = sorted(d, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
print(d_sorted)
```